# Firestore arrayUnion returns FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update an array in firestore with React and node Firebase SDK (not the admin SDK) using the arrayUnion and I get an error that reads:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field requestIDs in document usernames/tester/projects/default)

For the life of me I have not been able to figure out what why I am getting this error as my code will update the value without using the arrayUnion so it is fielding the location. I have tried the other similar asked questions and have not gotten it to work.

some code:
firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: xxxx,
  authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxx"
};


// initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) 
{
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
else 
{
    firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use this one
}

export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export default firebase

export const storage = firebase.storage();

export const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp;

export const arrayUnion=(data) =>{
  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data);
}

export const TimestampToDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.toDate;
```

commissions.services.js file

```
import { firestore, arrayUnion } from "../firebase";

// get ref to projects
const getProjectRef = (username) =>{
  return firestore.collection('usernames').doc(username).collection('projects').doc('default');
};



// add docID to requestIDs array
const updateProjectColumns= (id, username ) =>{
  return getProjectRef(username).update({'requestIDs': arrayUnion(id)});
}

const CommissionService = {
  updateProjectColumns
};

export default CommissionService;
```

ButtonRequest.js

```
import CommissionService from '../../services/commissions.service';
// relevant code
const handleClick = () => {
     CommissionService.updateProjectColumns(props.docID, props.requestData.data().commissionedArtist);

  };
```

My CommissionService.updateProjectColumns  is the problem. The props are working and if I substitute a test string for the the [arrayUnion(id)] portion it will update the document just erasing the array that was already there with the string.

All the docs on Firestore say that this is the way to use the arrayUnion function. Even if that field value was not an array, according to the docs, the function should make it an array with only the added value.

sample doc in firestore

```
requestIDs: [
  "test String"
]
```

docs are here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=2#node.js_11

The only difference I can see is that I am not using the admin SDK but the function seems the same in the client side SDK. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because:

```
export const arrayUnion=(data) =>{
  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data);
}
```

...has no return statement. So I think you want...

```
export const arrayUnion=(data) =>{
  return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data);
}
```

To generalize (in case `data` has more than one value, like an array) you may want to do:

```
export const arrayUnion=(data) =>{
  return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...data);
}
```

Comment: You wonderful amazing person! I have spent hours trying to solve this! I did try the general solution but since the data is a string it (...data) will parse each letter in the string and add them as elements in the array. The (data) works beautifully as expected thank-you so much.