# Where can I find arrayUnion in firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

So there is array-union in firebase client app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

I'd like to use arrayUnion on my server, where I use firebase-admin and don't need to go through the usual firebase client permission rules.

But there is no such import in firebase-admin, and if I try to use arrayUnion helper from firebase client in firebase-admin doc.update, although it type checks, I have a runtime error that the object is not recognized as an update value, which error is very much akin to the one reported here [Firestore arrayUnion returns FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308510/firestore-arrayunion-returns-firebaseerror-function-documentreference-update).

I came to think that firebase-admin doesn't support arrayUnion. Is that right, and if not, how can I use it?

Comment: Did you try https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_12? If so, can you edit your question to include a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen your comment made me revise the issue with fresh perspective. Apparently, I was importing arrayUnion from 'firebase/...' but I was using the API of 'firebase-admin/...'. After correcting this, runtime errors have gone. I'm still perplexed why their typing allowed me to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was importing arrayUnion from 'firebase/...' but I was using the API of 'firebase-admin/...'. After correcting this, runtime errors have gone. I'm still perplexed why their typing allowed me to do this though.

Answer (score 3):

Try importing the `FieldValue` class from the "admin" SDK:

```
import { FieldValue } from "firebase-admin/firestore"
```

To use the array union method, simply call `FieldValue.arrayUnion(itemToAddToArrayHere)`.

Example Usage:

```
adminApp.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`).update({
      operations: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(operationID)
});
```